# SQL join with date function

Tags: sql

i have 2 tables :

table customer

```
id   city  first_enter_date
```

and table activity:

```
id  date_id  total_time
```

I need to extract total_time 15 days from the first_enter_date for customer from tel-aviv

thanks all

Comment: It will be helpful if you describe your tables a bit.

Comment: how are `customer` and `activity` related?  What is the database engine (mysql, postgresql, oracle)?

Comment: they are related by id column

Comment: It would help if you added the tag of the database you are using, e.g. oracle, and the data types of the table columns.